# Finding the all integers solutions (x,y)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers (x,y), such that

$5x^2-6xy+7y^2=383$

Comment: @Ewin, the community standards require you to show some work before anyone can help you. Could you please explain what you have tried so far so people can attempt to help you?

Comment: Five questions in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The discriminant of $5x^2-6xy+7y^2=383\iff 5x^2-x(6y)+7y^2-383=0\ \ \ \ (1)$

is $\displaystyle (6y)^2-4\cdot5(7y^2-383)=4(383\cdot5-26y^2)$

As $x$ is real, $\displaystyle383\cdot5-26y^2\ge0\implies y^2<74$

We can reduce the  calculation by half as :

If $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution of $(1);$ so will be $(-x_1,-y_1)$

or if $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of $\displaystyle ax^2+bx+c=0,$

$-x_1,-x_2$ will the roots of $\displaystyle ax^2-bx+c=0$

If $f(x,y)=5x^2-6xy+(7y^2-383),f(x,-y)=5x^2+6xy+(7y^2-383)$